# Laravel 7 - Blade IF

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need some help. I have separate sections in my blade template which I would like not to be shown if there are no values to display.

This is the section I want to hide if there are no entries.

```html
<div class="card-incident-details-other card-incident-details ">
                <h4>Other Skills Used</h4>
                <ul>@foreach ($skillsused as $skillused)
                        @if ($skillused->SkillName->gid === 4)
                    <li>{{ $skillused->SkillName->skills_name }}</li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach</ul>
                </div>
```

However I'm struggling and need some help please.

Essentially, I need to do something like:

```html
    @if (count($skillused->SkillName->gid == 4) > 0)
                <div class="card-incident-details-other card-incident-details ">
                <h4>Other Skills Used</h4>
                <ul>@foreach ($skillsused as $skillused)
                        @if ($skillused->SkillName->gid === 4)
                    <li>{{ $skillused->SkillName->skills_name }}</li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach</ul>
                </div>
    @endif
```

But this returns an error:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: /var/www/html/basics/resources/views/incidents/viewincident.blade.php)

dd($skill**s**used):

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#366 ?
  #items: array:2 [?
    0 => App\SkillUsed {#367 ?
      #table: "skills_used"
      #primaryKey: "usage_id"
      +timestamps: false
      #fillable: array:3 [?]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [?
        "usage_id" => 104
        "sid" => 1
        "incident_id" => 66
      ]
      #original: array:3 [?
        "usage_id" => 104
        "sid" => 1
        "incident_id" => 66
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [?]
    }
    1 => App\SkillUsed {#368 ?
      #table: "skills_used"
      #primaryKey: "usage_id"
      +timestamps: false
      #fillable: array:3 [?]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [?
        "usage_id" => 105
        "sid" => 3
        "incident_id" => 66
      ]
      #original: array:3 [?
        "usage_id" => 105
        "sid" => 3
        "incident_id" => 66
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [?]
    }
  ]
}
```

dd($skillused)

```
App\SkillUsed {#366 ▼
  #table: "skills_used"
  #primaryKey: "usage_id"
  +timestamps: false
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    "usage_id" => 85
    "sid" => 1
    "incident_id" => 55
  ]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "usage_id" => 85
    "sid" => 1
    "incident_id" => 55
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "SkillName" => App\Skill {#381 ▼
      #table: "skills"
      #primaryKey: "did"
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: "mysql"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "sid" => 1
        "gid" => 2
        "skills_name" => "Patient Assessment"
        "deleted" => 0
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▼
        "sid" => 1
        "gid" => 2
        "skills_name" => "Patient Assessment"
        "deleted" => 0
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you `dd($skillused)` and show the result, so we know what the data looks like?

Comment: @AndySong Done buddy. However, there is a relationship on the SkillUsed model which links to a different table hence the $skillused->SkillName->gid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple filter to do this:

```php
if($skillsused->filter(function ($v) {
    return $v->SkillName->gid === 4;
})->count() > 0)
```

If you have PHP 7.4 and above:

```php
if($skillsused->filter(fn ($v) => $v->SkillName->gid === 4)->count() > 0)
```

Comment: I added this (bottom) to my blade view and got this error message. Call to undefined method App\SkillUsed::filter() (View: /var/www/html/basics/resources/views/incidents/viewincident.blade.php).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear, you can only pass an array or a collection of models into the `count` helper function. This `$skillused->SkillName->gid` is a single instance of a model not to mention your accessing `gid` so technically your passing an `integer` into the `count` function. To fix your error refactor your code to look like this:

```php
// I believe this `$skillsused` variable is the collection given your looping through it.

// Model collections comes with a count method for convenience so we use that instead.
@if ($skillsused->count() > 0) 
    <div class="card-incident-details-other card-incident-details">
         <h4>Other Skills Used</h4>
         <ul>
             @foreach ($skillsused as $skillused)
                 @if ($skillused->SkillName->gid === 4)
                   <li>{{ $skillused->SkillName->skills_name }}</li>
                 @endif
             @endforeach
         </ul>
     </div>
@endif
```

Following your comment below, this should yield the desired result:

```php
@if ($skillsused->count() > 0) 

    @php $displayBlock = false; @endphp

    @foreach ($skillsused as $skillused)
        @if ($skillused->SkillName->gid === 4) $displayBlock = true @endif
    @endforeach

    @if ($displayBlock)
        <div class="card-incident-details-other card-incident-details">
         <h4>Other Skills Used</h4>
         <ul>
             @foreach ($skillsused as $skillused)
                 @if ($skillused->SkillName->gid === 4)
                   <li>{{ $skillused->SkillName->skills_name }}</li>
                 @endif
             @endforeach
         </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
@endif
```

This is clunky if you ask me but if it solves your problem then fine, consider moving it to a blade component.

Comment: Hi Tsommie, That would work well, however I only want to show this segment IF $skillused->SkillName->gid === 4 has a count of more than 0 and not just $skillsused has a count of more than 0 (as gid 1 may have an entry). gid relates to the segment... so gid 1 is one segment. gid 2 is another... and so forth...

Comment: $skillused->SkillName->gid === 4 && (isset($skillused->SkillName->gid) && count($killused->SkillName->gid) > 0) something like that

Comment: Ok lets fact check...You cant count this `$skillused->SkillName->gid === 4` because its a logic than returns a `boolean`. And you cant access this `$skillused` without first looping through your collection first. what you can do is to count the collection to make sure there is a record in it like so: `$skillsused->count() > 0` which should return a `boolean`. Next, check if `$skillused->SkillName->gid === 4` which will also return a `boolean` but can only be done after a loop. So in my opinion and experience, I believe the answer I gave is sufficient...

Comment: ...else you want to move that portion of your blade file to a view that displays a single resource where you can check `$skillused->SkillName->gid === 4` directly without running a loop, mind you if your not dealing with a collection or an array you CAN NOT USE `count` method or helper!!!!!!!